# Sentence to lower case - Why split first?

Tags: python, pandas, lowercase, nlp

I am learning the basics of how to process text data, and I am currently on the preprocessing operation of converting sentences to lower case. All tutorials I find do the following:

```
train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: \
                     ' '.join([word.lower() for word \
                               in str(x).split()])
```

But in my opinion, the more convenient call can be the following

```
train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: str(x).lower())
```

I totally understand that they produce different results, because the first call also converts all whitespace characters to " ", whereas the other one preserves them.

```
all(train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: str(x).lower()) == \
    train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word.lower() \
                         for word in str(x).split()])))
---------------------------------------------------------------
False
```

But if we split only by " ", they will be the same

```
all(train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: str(x).lower()) == \
    train['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word.lower() \
                         for word in str(x).split(" ")])))
---------------------------------------------------------------
True
```

If everyone does split-then-convert, what is more advantageous about this approach in practice?

Comment: I don't see any reason to split first. Converting a white-space to lower does absolutely nothing. The different results that you're getting is because if you split-convert and join, all types of white-spaces (space, tab, etc) get converted to a space.

Comment: I bet `' '.join([w.lower() for w in str(x).split()])` and `' '.join(str(x).lower().split())` would produce same results.

Comment: I totally agree with What @MuhammadAhmad says, you are misunderstood the concept, anyway to convert series into lower case, the convenient way `train['tweet'].str.lower()`